# How to take in put from radio select in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, radio-button, django-views

Hi i am making a form and want user to select radio button.

**#model.py**

```
class UniData(models.Model):
    universityName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (0 , 'Not Sent'),
        (1 , 'Sent'),
    )

    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=0)

class UniForm(ModelForm):

    universityName = models.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="University Name")

    class Meta:
       GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (0 , 'Not Sent'),
        (1 , 'Sent'),
      )
        model = UniData
        fields = ['universityName',gender',]
        widgets = {
            'universityName': TextInput(attrs={'value':'University Name', 'class':'default-value',}),
            'gender': RadioSelect(choices=GENDER_CHOICES),
```

Is this write way to use radioSelect? Also how should i write view for storing the selected value of the gender radio button by the user and then how can i display it in my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you deal with any other form, try:

```
def view(request):
    if request.POST:
        f = UniForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            f.save()
        else:
            ...draw form with errors... 
    else:
        ...draw form...
```

You should read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/). It will explain everything.

Also you have a typo with quotes in your code, please, be more attentive.